# ASP.NET doesn't have Object Pooling in standard like in Java EE?

Tags: java, asp.net, jakarta-ee

I read this [C# Object Pooling Pattern implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-object-pooling-pattern-implementation) so my question: does one have to implement own Object Pooling strategy in ASP.NET whereas this exists in Java EE?

Well I'm upset as I prefer .net platform to java, but here in java it's done without being a guru. I'm surprised ASP.NET didn't implement at least the same and even better.

Comment: The lack of data connection pooling being built in drives me BERSERK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've learned that .NET covers this for atleast some scenarios.

[BufferManager Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager.aspx)

Is an object pool for buffers. I don't see any readily available way to extend this for other purposes short of decompiliation & reverse engineering. However it's possible that a more usable class exists somewhere deep in .NET.

Also in regards to [C# Object Pooling Pattern implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510975/c-object-pooling-pattern-implementation) the complexity involved in this will reduce substantially with .NET 4.0 having been released. The majority (or all) of the locking code could completely be swept away and replaced with the Concurrent data classes.

Comment: Well I'm upset as I prefer .net platform to java, but here in java it's done without being a guru. I'm surprised ASP.NET didn't implement at least the same and even better.

Comment: Yes it would've been a great addition to the concurrent data classes they added if they had created a generic concurrent object pool class.